# Updating java version to 8 on ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, updates, java

I would like to update my java version (UPDATE, not install) on my ubuntu 12.04 computer. I currently have java 7.x, and I would like to update it to the newest version possible (8.0 at least) without it being too complicated.

Comment: Do you remember as to how you installed java in the first place?

Comment: No, it was so long ago

Comment: Which java are you asking about? Oracle or Openjdk?

Comment: You may want to add the output of "java -version" to your question.

Comment: Also, the earliest Ubuntu version to have openjdk-8 directly available is 14.10

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Java 8 is not available in the Ubuntu 12.04 repositories, but it is available from a Launchpad PPA.

You also cannot update a Java version to the next Java version, *but* you can install different Java versions side by side.

To install Java version 8 (**OpenJDK 8 edition** - not ORACLE Java 8) open a terminal and execute :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:openjdk-r/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk
```

If you only want to install the Java Runtime Environment :

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jre
```

**Note 1 :**

As you said "... without it being too complicated ...", I assumed that you installed Java 7 from the Ubuntu repositories, which contain OpenJDK and did not add the WebUpd8 PPA (ORACLE Java).

**Note 2 :**

As you said that you get the `File "/usr/bin/add-apt-repository", line 37 print _("The %s named '%s' has no PPA named '%s'" ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax` error, have a look [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/727493/344926).

**Suggestion :**

Keep both versions installed side by side, some other packages or programs might rely on Java 7.

*However, when you don't want to have both versions and if don't need Java 7 anymore ... remove it.*

Comment: It says that I cannot add the PPA:

`File "/usr/bin/add-apt-repository", line 37
    print _("The %s named '%s' has no PPA named '%s'" 
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Answer (score 6):

As you did not specify whether you want to install OpenJDK or Oracle JDK, my answer covers Oracle JDK.

It is interesting to quote this text from [here](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/01/install-oracle-java-jdk-7-in-ubuntu-via.html). What follows applies to **JDK8** too and for all Ubuntu versions of yours or higher.

> Oracle JDK7 itself is not hosted in the PPA because that's not allowed
>   by the new Java license (which is also the reason why it has been
>   removed from the official Ubuntu repositories); the package in the PPA
>   automatically downloads Oracle Java JDK 7 from its official website
>   and installs it on your Ubuntu / Linux Mint computer, just like the
>   flashplugin-installer package does.

[Note](https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/java) that **JDK9** is expected to be released during this year, so do not try to use before that.

For this reason, this is is how to install (and not update) your Java 8 version:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

Comment: cl-netbox gave directions to install OpenJDK, not Oracle. OP did not specify whish one he|she asked about.

Comment: You are right, thank you for the note. I updated.

Answer (score 3):

Adding to the earlier answers...I had issues with my JAVA_HOME after the install from this ppa following this commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-set-default
```

The 4th command doesn't work as expected. So in my case I have to manually run these commands:

```
sudo /etc/environment(add the below two lines and append to PATH if needed)
JAVA_HOME=/path-to-java-before-bin-directory
export JAVA_HOME

sudo source /etc/environment
```

and then it was working fine.
verify it also:

```
root@ashu-700-430qe:/DataStax_POC# which java
/usr/bin/java
root@ashu-700-430qe:/DataStax_POC# java -version
java version "1.8.0_66"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_66-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.66-b17, mixed mode)
root@ashu-700-430qe:/DataStax_POC#
```

I referred this [link](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/09/install-oracle-java-8-in-ubuntu-via-ppa.html). Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

If you want keep both versions, and switch depending on your needs, consider the command:

`update-java-alternatives`

to make sure that a particular java (sun-java) is the default runtime. Use `update-java-alternatives --list` to display all possible options, and `update-java-alternatives --set <java version name from --list>` to switch it.

Comment: Java is tricky to configure using the alternatives, since it has many components. This is why there is the `update-java-alternatives` command. You should update your answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is the Zulu port of OpenJDK which can be downloaded as a zip file, unpacked and used directly.

If needing to run from the command line, consider prepending the bin directory to $PATH in .bash_profile.

Downloads available at http://www.azul.com/downloads/zulu/zulu-linux/

(untested as I do not have a 12.04 system available.  It appears though that the requirement of glibc being at least 2.5 is satisfied)

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution is to add the PPA repository from the project [ubuntu-justched](https://github.com/glasswalk3r/ubuntu-justched)available in the Github. This will provide a little bit different solution because it will download the Oracle JRE tarball to a previously configured directory and generate a DEB package from it.

That way you won't depend on somebody else packing the JRE, you will do it yourself (don't worry, it will be a automatic process).