# PPAs cannot be added on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, ppa, add-apt-repository

Whenever I try to do something like
`sudo add-apt-repository ...`
It gives me the following error message:

```
File "/usr/bin/add-apt-repository", line 37
    print _("The %s named '%s' has no PPA named '%s'" 
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

This is really frustrating, as I cannot add ANY PPAs.

Comment: As the error says "syntax error", did you try correcting it? I mean   'sudo gedit /usr/bin/add-apt-repository' and editing the line 37 to this:  `print (_("The %s named '%s' has no PPA named '%s'"))`            . instead of this :  `print _("The %s named '%s' has no PPA named '%s'"`

Comment: I am not sure about this. I just guessed it as it was giving "syntax error".  Please wait for someone with better knowledge answers this. (Or try it at your own risk :P)

Comment: Severus Tux is right. There is a syntax error. Must be `print (_(...` You can change with `sudo gedit` or equivalent, or via GUI. I you need more help just let us know. I wonder how that happened in the first place!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out my python version was by default 3.x instead of 2.x, that caused all the problems. I fixed it like [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/880461/499143).

Answer (score 2):

There is a syntax error in the `add-apt-repository` file.

Open a terminal and execute :

```
sudo apt-get update  
sudo apt-get install gksu  
gksudo gedit /usr/bin/add-apt-repository
```

Add **`(`** to the beginning and **`))`** at the end of the command

```
print _("The %s named '%s' has no PPA named '%s'"
```

... so that the print command afterwards correctly reads ->

```
print(_("The %s named '%s' has no PPA named '%s'"))
```

Save the file - now you should be able to add repositories.

Note : Here is the the link to the PPA you want to add ->
https://launchpad.net/~openjdk-r/+archive/ubuntu/ppa

There you can see, that the command in the Java 8 answer
`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:openjdk-r/ppa` is correct.

Comment: having open brackets and without corresponding close brackets is the key here - you need the close brackets in the answer.  Point the OP towards launchpad is more important - changing a system file points to a more important bug that needs to be patched.  BTW _("...") is valid python2 syntax - (_("...")) is python3 (also backward compatible with python2)

Comment: @cl-netbox Thanks, this helped. But now another problem has risen:  when I run it, it says that there is an error at `os.umask(0022): Invalid token`. What does this mean, and how canI fix it?

Comment: @cl-netbox Also, when I tried to comment out the line (to see what happens),  it gave me yet an `ImportError`: `No module named softwareproperties`

Comment: @SergeyIchtchenko Check whether `software-properties-common` is installed with : `apt-cache policy software-properties-common` If the package is not installed, execute : `sudo apt-get install software-properties-common` Now add a repository : `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:<ppa-name>` Afterwards update the software sources by running : `sudo apt-get update`

Comment: @cl-netbox Sorry, didn't help. Any other ideas? I was told that maybe updating my OS to a newer version might help.

Comment: @SergeyIchtchenko Then follow exactly this suggestion ... Ubuntu 12.04 will not be supported after April this year any longer ... but do not upgrade - better perform a clean installation ... this OS is way too old ! :)

Comment: @cl-netbox Alright. By "clean installation" do you mean removing all files and installing a new version, or keeping them and reinstalling the OS?

Comment: @SergeyIchtchenko I mean backup your personal stuff and install the new system (Ubuntu 16.04 LTS or Ubuntu 16.10) completely from scratch and then restore the personal files or place them on a separate partition. :)

Comment: @cl-netbox Thanks for all that help. Turns out that the problem was in my default python version (the /usr/bin/python symlink pointing to python3 and not python2) and I managed to fix it. Thanks again.